# Migrating Rails app to Grails - Can I easily use an int for the ID field of all the domain classes?

Tags: grails, types

If so how do I do it?  I tried just using a declaration id type: 'int' but it got an error when calling Find on the class.

Comment: Can you post some example code? Grails uses an int called 'id' by default so I'm not sure why you'd need a custom mapping?

Comment: In the version of grails I am using, 1.1.1 it uses a bigint by default, not an int.  But I am trying to use a legacy database where the ids or int.  I'm having numerous problems because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you simply have to declare the id field as a member.

```
class MyDomainClass {
    int id
}
```